# using include between 3 entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entities

```
 public class Sale
{
    public Sale()
    {
        SalesDetails = new List<SalesDetail>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int SaleId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalTotal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }
}
 public class SalesDetail
{

    [Key]
    public int SaleDetailsId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Sale Sales { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I using Entity Framework How get the data from 3 entities using include
I want to get total from Sale and quantity from SaleDetail and Product Name from Product (with SaleID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Incluse(string path)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) method that allow you to include not directly related properties. For example:

```
var salesWithLoadedSubentities = dbContext
                                  .Sales
                                  .Include("SalesDetails")
                                  .Include("SalesDetails.Products");
```

Now your collection will contains `Sale` entities with perloaded details and products.

Also, You can use [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy) for your context but it's not recommended because it can cause performance issues in the production environment.